# Migrating publish states from 2013 SP1 to 8.5

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, 2013-sp1-hr1

I need to migrate publish states from old Publication Target with 2 destinations to 2 separate CD Environments.
I am aware of the following article for re-purposing old publish states:

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-web-8-migrating-from-old-to-new-style-publishing-part-1-of-3-the-cmdlet

but I want to migrate states to one CD environment, and then duplicate the same states for second CD environment, since they were under the same Publication target in the past.

I can migrate states to one CD environment, and then republish all content to the second one, but publishing will take at least a month.

Has anyone had this issue and have they modified the script to accommodate it?

Comment: I have used that script for a successful upgrade and migration to TopMan from 2013. There should be an option for publish states as far as i remember. Have you tried the script in a sandbox env to see how it behaves?

Answer (score 1):

I have used it for my migration as well but have not encountered the above scenario. Looking at the help file for "`Convert-TcmPublishStates`", this may not be feasible. The only 2 parameters that are allowed in the script for the Source are Publication Targets and Target Types. The script basically modifies the `PUBLISH_STATES` table along with the references, among the other things.

The destination is generally stored in the `PUBLICATION_TARGETS` table and is used to store the endpoint with the mode of transport for the deployer. I suggest not modifying the script. See notes and recommendations from the developers :).

```
Do not attempt to change, decompile, or modify the cmdlet, which uses internal methods and queries created by SDL Web R&D.
```

Rather than duplicating the destination, can you not consume content that is published to one envrironment? I do not know your use cases but can avoid republishing of content (which is the goal of using TcmPublishStates).